# What does this asbestos remediation report mean?

Tags: asbestos, inspection

What does this asbestos testing result mean?

[image: Asbestos Test Report]

Background: My wife and I are looking to buy a house built in the 1950s. The seller disclosed that they have had an asbestos abatement done and health certifications issued. This is the documentation they gave on the asbestos testing. I'm still waiting for the health certification.

Comment: Have you tried calling the laboratory (EMSL Analytical) and asking them?

Comment: That's not a report.  That's a test result.  It will later become an attachment to a report. The report will explain what it means.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an on-site analysis of "fibers" in the air after remediation. Often we require a remediation company to test the air after they have abated the asbestos to certify that they have removed all the asbestos and the air is now "clean" and suitable for inhabitants.

This is certifying the "fiber count" in the air. There should be a certification that they removed 100% of the asbestos, (chrysotile).

If you see a report that says they tested a sample and it has more than 1% Chrysotile, then that is asbestos.

I'd call the testing agency and ask for a "complete" copy of the file.